# Byte ordering in byte buffer for big endian

Tags: java, endianness, bytebuffer

I know little endian and big endian are explained thousends of times online, but i'm still confused.

If you have a byte buffer that is set to use big endian. And you have:

```
short value = 4660; // corresponds to 0x1234
```

When you do:

```
bb.putShort( 16, value );
```

Will the byte 0x12 be at index 16 and 0x34 at index 17. Or will 0x34 be at index 16 and 0x12 at index 17? I get confused by the descriptions online.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you write a simple test application to figure that out for yourself?

Comment: 'Big-endian' means that the big end of the number is at the lowest address value.  Surely you've read that definition 1000 times? It makes your question tautological.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take `0x12345678` for example.

**One way to look at it:**

```
Endianess | Least Significant Byte | Most Significant Byte  | In Memory
----------|------------------------|------------------------|-----------
Big       | In The Highest Address | In The Lowest  Address | 0x12345678
----------|------------------------|------------------------|-----------
Little    | In The Lowest  Address | In The Highest Address | 0x78563412
```

**Another way to look at it:**

```
Endianess | In The Lowest Address  | In The Highest Address | In Memory
----------|------------------------|------------------------|-----------
Big       | Most Significant Byte  | Least Significant Byte | 0x12345678
----------|------------------------|------------------------|-----------
Little    | Least Significant Byte | Most Significant Byte  | 0x78563412
```

---

If you're looking for a way to memorize this, then notice that each method makes sense in its own way:

- Big-Endian, because it is similar to the way we write numbers (starting from the highest digit)
- Little-Endian, because the least significant byte is stored in the lowest address

Answer (score 1):

You can figure this out by writing 6 (!) lines of code.

```
ByteBuffer allocate = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
allocate.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
allocate.putShort((short) 0x1234);
allocate.rewind();
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(allocate.get()));
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(allocate.get()));
```

Tip: "Big End"-ian has the last byte at the last address. So the memory is exactly how you would read it as `0x12 0x34`.